# Assign result of single operation method to variable before returning or just return?

Tags: java, coding-style, return, variable-assignment

do you prefer writing method with immediate return of result to assigning it firstly to variable? To be clear we only consider situation presented below when no other operations are done in method body.

First option:

```
private List<Integer> getIdsOfUsersLoggedWithinLastHour() {
     return userDAO.getUsersLoggedWithinLastHour().stream().map(User::Id).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Second option:

```
    private List<Integer> getIdsOfUsersLoggedWithinLastHour() {
         List<Integer> ids = userDAO.getUsersLoggedWithinLastHour().stream().map(User::Id).collect(Collectors.toList());
         return ids;
    }
```

IMHO there is no need to assign result of method operations to variable when you do nothing with it and just return. The return type is declared in method signature so you can easily check it. The code cleanliness is about the same. You use some additional memory and cpu operations (maybe not so important today but it is always something additional). Friend of mine claims that initializing variable is better for easier debugging and further code development but I think it is redundant and can be done when you really need this, not 'for future'. What is your opinion?

Answer (score 4):

In many cases I plump for the second option and, in the cited case, I almost certainly would.

This allows you to place a breakpoint on `return ids;` which can be helpful when debugging. (Inspecting the contents of a CPU register is an option in low level languages like C, but I don't *think* that is available for JVM-based languages).

A series of functions that return an anonymous temporary up the stack can be difficult to debug.

I wouldn't worry about any overhead that the second choice introduces: that ought to be optimised out and declaring an extra reference variable is unlikely to cause a performance bottleneck even if it was not optimised out. (Note that in C++ it *will* be optimised out via a process called *Named Return Value Optimisation* and I imagine that Java would follow suit.) Remember that being able to debug and maintain code is as important as *elegance*; whatever that means in this particular instance.

Comment: IDEs are helpful when you need to debug and with 2 clicks you can create variable and initialize it. You also have some evaluators, watches, etc. to evaluate expression value immediately when step on the breakpoint. Isn't it redundant then to add extra code when you don't really need it? In my opinion you can always separate it when there is such need.

Comment: This is the problem when attempting to answer what is essentially an opinion-based question. But I disagree with "you don't really need it". You quite possibly to when attempting to *debug* your code. I tend to rely on a compiler to remove things like trivial assignments during its optimisation process. In short, I trust the compiler to do this more than I trust myself.

Comment: I agree that in debug process it can be helpful and compiler could optimise that. But from code cleanliness point of view it is not elegant and redundant. Using this approach everywhere in code when we have such methods would not look good.

Comment: I admit I use it quite sparingly. Boost in C++ use the first option and it always irritates me (especially given that NVRO is allowed to optimise it out). It can be very difficult to see what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

I assign result to the variable only when need to do some logic with it before returning value from the method. Otherwise I use coding style from the first example - makes code concise.

Second code style can help during debug process sometimes, but you shouldn't commit this IMHO

Also, if you inspect second example with any popular static analysis tool it would give a result like `"local variable is redundant"` which is one more reason to eliminate those vars in real projects.

Good article about this design issue: http://www.yegor256.com/2015/09/01/redundant-variables-are-evil.html

But you must understand that it's only a *common practice*, nobody can make you do not use redundant variables - code works with them correctly, it's only a question of taste like many other design principles

Comment: When you do some logic you need to assign to variable, nobody likes 'train wrecks'. Either like you I prefer first option to second. I also agree that it can be helpful during debug but you can use this coding-style when you need to debug this specific place in code

Comment: If you like this way and think this is a good answer then do upvote it. I think, by the way, that the downvote is unwarranted. But that is the pitfall in answering an opinion-based question.

Comment: You are right. I will wait, maybe someone will provide some articles or whatever that proves somehow that one style is better than other. That is true it is opinion-based question and it depends on somebody's preferences. I just wanted to hear other coders opinion.